# Растянуть слово по ширине div

Tags: html, css

Есть определенное слово, нужно его растянуть по ширине `div` Можно изменить `letter-spacing` но блок резиновый, как подобрать непонятно. Возможно ли решить на CSS без скриптов и не разбивая слово на элементы?

Comment: вы знаете конкретное количество букв в слове? или слово каждый раз может быть разным?

Comment: Допустим знаем, хотя второй вариант еще интереснее)))

Comment: тогда может [подойти вот это решение](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557411/css-letter-spacing-percent-to-completely-fit-the-div-container) из аналогичного вопроса

Answer (score 4):

каждой букве одеваешь span и родителю text-align: justify;

например:

```
 <div style="text-align: justify;">
 <span>С</span><span>л</span><span>о</span><span>в</span><span>о</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Снизу то же вариант. Но он плох в плане seo и вообще костыльный. Интересуют красивые решения

Comment: Это хорошее решение для вашей задачи. Скорее всего у вас задача неправильно поставлена.

Answer (score 2):

Помещаем нужное слово в тэг списка, добавляем флексбокс и растягиваем по экрану, например, вот так:

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
  text-align: center;
padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  flex: 1 10%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>О</li>
  <li>ф</li>
  <li>и</li>
  <li>г</li>
  <li>е</li>
  <li>т</li>
  <li>ь</li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: Даже интересно стало, кто минусанул...

Comment: Совет хороший, но тот же метод получается. Хочется слово оставить как есть. А оформление через CSS

Answer (score 1):

В итоге вставил между буквами пробелы и выровнял через `text-align: justify;` Если у кого есть более цивилизованное предложение, буду очень рад.